# Super formula on shader

Tags: 2d, shaders, geometry, fragment-shader, trigonometry

I'm using [Shader-toy](https://www.shadertoy.com) to experiment and try to learn a bit the shader science.
As exercise I wan to replicate some of the wikipedia math plots. I've started with a [Super Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula).

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

(taken from [this wikipedia image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/Superformula.gif))

This image shows the parameter of the super formula thing:

- *a=b=1*,
- *m=3*,
- *n1=5*,
- *n2=18* and
- *n3=18*

I've looked for a [similar example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdXXDB), simplified it and try to reproduce my curve.

In shader-toy this is my code:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Variables to be fed into the formula
    float a = 1.0;
    float b = 1.0;
    float m = 3.;
    float n1 = 5.0;
    float n2 = 18.;
    float n3 = 18.;

    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

    // translation
    vec2 sf = uv - 0.5;

    // r of the current point
    float pr = sqrt(sf.x*sf.x + sf.y*sf.y);
    // Angle (Phi) of the current point
    float f = atan(sf.y/sf.x);

    // The formula itself. Division by 10.0 added to scale the result down a bit.
    float r = pow((pow(abs(cos(f*m/4.0)/a),n2) + pow(abs(sin(f*m/4.0)/b), n3)), -(1.0/n1)) / 10.;

    // Output with coloring by relative radius
    fragColor = (pr <= r) ? 
        vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.0) : 
        vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

But I'm achieving a different shape:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `atan(sf.y/sf.x)`, use `atan(sf.y,sf.x)`. This works because it takes the sign into consideration. Dividing the two numbers loses the sign bit data, so which quadrant you are in is unknown.

You can add `fragColor=vec4(pr,f,0.0,1.0);` to see what is going on.

Also, if you want to fix your aspect ratio (the image stretching) add `sf.y *= iResolution.y/iResolution.x;` after the declaring sf.